# How set css correctly for text-field on gluon-mobile?

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

[image]

The image shows what happens when a textfield is selected. It turns white although it should stay the same as the field above. Also the passwordfield shows strange icons - but thats another question.

Here the code:

```
.text-field {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -fx-border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -fx-background-radius:30;
    -fx-border-radius:30;
    -fx-min-height:45;
    -fx-text-fill: #fff;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: #fff;
    -fx-border-width:0px;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-font-size: 1.2em;
    -fx-effect: null;
}

.text-field:hover,
.text-field:focused,
.text-field:selected {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -fx-border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -fx-background-radius:30;
    -fx-border-radius:30;
    -fx-min-height:45;
    -fx-text-fill: #fff;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: #fff;
    -fx-border-width:0px;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-font-size: 1.2em;
    -fx-effect: null;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my css or is it a bug maybe? Css is showing properly when i launch the app on desktop. But deployed the texfields are white.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which `TextField` are you using, `CharmTextField` or the JDK one? Your code works for me, when I install it on an Android device (but the `TextField` shows a copy marker)

Comment: I have tried out both, with the same result... To mention deployed to iOS. Ideas?

Comment: I'm using Gluon on Android only, so I can't test it on iOS. Have you tried the more specific selector: `.charm-text-field > .text-field` ?

Comment: Yes, without luck either. Still white and but now with a little bit of the swatch-color too. I dont have an image but mostly the same as above.

Does anyone maybe have a css example for textfield on iOS working as expected?

Comment: I've just tested your CSS on my iPad, and it works fine when you select the textfield and start typing. There is a glitch when you close the keyboard and it shows a white textfield with black text for a few milliseconds, but then it stays as your first textfield.